# Flink throwing java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer pool is destroyed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Need help! can someone guide me to the right path?

Following is the snippet of my code and log.

```
DataStream<ObjectNode> stream = env.addSource(KafkaConsumer.getKafkaConsumer());
DataStream<MyDataObject> dataStream = stream.flatMap(new DataTransformation());
```

I am using flatMapFunction, to process my input object and get multiple object.

Following is the stackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer pool is destroyed.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:75) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:39) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:797) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:775) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.data.transformation.DataTransformation.flatMap(DataTransformation.java:68) [eventproducer.jar:na]
    at com.data.transformation.DataTransformation.flatMap(DataTransformation.java:23) [eventproducer.jar:na]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:47) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:422) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:407) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:797) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:775) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:272) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:261) [flink-connector-kafka-base_2.10-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka010Fetcher.emitRecord(Kafka010Fetcher.java:88) [flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.10-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.runFetchLoop(Kafka09Fetcher.java:157) [flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:255) [flink-connector-kafka-base_2.10-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:78) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:56) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:272) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:655) [flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffer pool is destroyed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestBuffer(LocalBufferPool.java:149) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestBufferBlocking(LocalBufferPool.java:138) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.sendToTarget(RecordWriter.java:131) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:88) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamRecordWriter.emit(StreamRecordWriter.java:86) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:72) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

EDIT:
Just for additional information, I am collection records using collect() and then passing all the records to the next operator for processing database insert operation. Where I am using flinks Cassandra Sink Connector.

Comment: Can you provide more of the code used in the project?

Comment: Hey, it happens inside flatMap() function, at the time of collect() method gets called.

Comment: Did anyone manage to figure cause of this issue? Having same problems with mapper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Buffer pool is destroyed" issue found in Apache Flink flapMap Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468495/buffer-pool-is-destroyed-issue-found-in-apache-flink-flapmap-operator)

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468495/buffer-pool-is-destroyed-issue-found-in-apache-flink-flapmap-operator/55469148 (It is not identical, but similar and this one has insuficcient extra information to come to a different answer).

Answer (score 0):

This can help.
Probably IO operations is taking more time.
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html

Answer (score 0):

Those situation can happen when your function throws an error which causes the operator to restart und cannot restore from a snapshot. Then this error is shown as flink restarts the job and the buffers are closed. There is a root exception prior to this